# Samsung DDR3 RAM modules

Tags: sdram

Trying figure out the compatibility of the following RAM modules from Samsung:

4GB 2Rx8-10600S-09-10-F2    M471B5273CH0-CH9   AND

4GB 2Rx8 10600S-09-10-F3   M471B5273CH0-CH9

the 1st module is the module in my notebook (HP pavilion dv6 3232TX)

second is the closest I have found thus far and need to know it they are both fitted are there likely to be an adverse ramifications?

Comment: "adverse **ram**ifications" - nice pun ;)

Answer (score 0):

The M471B5273CH0-CH9 part is the important bit. That is the part identity. So, I would say they should be quite compatible.